# How to control duplicate login process in seam

Tags: spring, jsf-2, seam, seam2, jboss-seam

my project is using JSF2.0, Seam 2.3 and Spring 3.0

login process is develop by Seam Security.

my problem is want to control the duplicate user login as follow:

Time1 :  User A @PC1 >>>>>> login system with userID: 11111 >>>>>>>>>> (Status:OK)

Time2 :  User B @PC2 >>>>>> login system with userID: 11111 >>>>>>>>>> (Status:OK)

At this time, i like to invalidate and logout automatically `User A` from system

How can i do this and any suggestion is welcome

Comment: How you find out `User A` or `User B` is legimate user who owns the `Original userID` before invalidating session of a user?

Comment: my awnser didn't work?

Comment: @Trind sorry for my late answer Trind. thanks so much for your solution and it's work. but we have to control other solution, so i solved this problem with my custom method. please kindly see my answer

Answer (score 1):

create a javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener and add it in your web XML.

save all the session in a list.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener, java.io.Serializable{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SessionListener.class);
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        listsession.add(event.getSession());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        listsession.remove(event.getSession());
    }
}
```

When a new session is registered compair if there is an existing one with the same user in the list. and use invalidateSession on it. can use something like this to get the seam components from the session

```
    for(HttpSession session:listsession){
        if (session!=null)
        {
            Identity identity = null;
            Credentials credentials = null;
            Object attribute = session.getAttribute("org.jboss.seam.security.identity");
            if (attribute instanceof Identity) 
            {
                identity = (Identity) attribute;
            }
            Object cred = session.getAttribute("org.jboss.seam.security.credentials");
            if (attribute instanceof Credentials) 
            {
                credentials = (Credentials) cred;
            }

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by this following idea:

Fist outject `LoginUserMap` and `LoginUserKeyMap` to session Scope when user login.

`LoginUserKeyMap` is to store userId with system know key.

eg: [key:user1, value:user120131010154566]

`LoginUserMap` is to store logged in user information list.

eg: [key:user120131010154566, value:object]

```
/**
 * Bijection Login User Map.
 */
@In(required = false, scope = ScopeType.APPLICATION, value = "loginUserMap")
@Out(required = false, scope = ScopeType.APPLICATION, value = "loginUserMap")
private Map<String, UserInfoBean> loginUserMap;

/**
 * Bijection Login User Key Map.
 */
@In(required = false, scope = ScopeType.APPLICATION, value = "loginUserKeyMap")
@Out(required = false, scope = ScopeType.APPLICATION, value = "loginUserKeyMap")
private Map<String, String> loginUserKeyMap;

public void doLogin() {

    // Generate User ID Key for duplicate user control.
    String key = CommonUtil.convertDateToString(new Date(), KEY_PATTERN);
    String userId = getCredentials().getUsername();
    String userIdKey = userId + key;

    if (getLoginUserMap() == null || getLoginUserKeyMap() == null) {

        // Initialize the Login User Map.
        setLoginUserMap(new HashMap());

        // Initialize the Login User Key Map.
        setLoginUserKeyMap(new HashMap());
    }

    // Check login User id is already login or not.
    if (getLoginUserKeyMap().containsKey(userId)) {

        log.info("Duplicate Login");

        // Get Current logged in User's Key.
        String CurrentUserKey = getLoginUserKeyMap().get(userId);

        // Get Current logged in User Information.
        UserInfoBean currentUserInfoBean = getLoginUserMap().get(CurrentUserKey);

        if (currentUserInfoBean != null) {

            // Set Duplicate flag true to Current logged User.
            currentUserInfoBean.setDuplicate(true);

            // Overwrite Current logged User Information.
            getLoginUserMap().put(CurrentUserKey, currentUserInfoBean);
        }

    }

    // Set New Login User Information.
    getUserInfoBean().setUserId(userId);
    getUserInfoBean().setUserIdKey(userIdKey);
    getUserInfoBean().setDuplicate(false);
    getUserInfoBean().setServiceStop(false);

    // Set New Login User Information and Key to Application Scope.
    getLoginUserKeyMap().put(userId, userIdKey);
    getLoginUserMap().put(userIdKey, getUserInfoBean());

}
```

And Then, create `checkStatus()` method

```
public void checkStatus() throws DuplicateLoginException, UserServiceStopException {

    if (getUserInfoBean() != null && getLoginUserMap() != null) {

        UserInfoBean currentUser = getLoginUserMap().get(getUserInfoBean().getUserIdKey());

        if (currentUser != null) {
            if (currentUser.isServiceStop()) {
                log.error("throw new UserServiceStopException()");
                throw new UserServiceStopException();

            } else if (currentUser.isDuplicate()) {
                log.error("throw new DuplicateLoginException()");
                throw new DuplicateLoginException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call that `checkStatus()` method from every page.

```
 <page view-id="/view/*">
    <action execute="#{UserStatusChecker.checkStatus()}" />
```

Now problem was overcome!!!!!